# Can't retrieve state of radio button

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I wan retrieve radio buttons, created in XML. It's OK. But when, I check if this radio button is checked, Android Studio tell me than the radio button retrieve is empty.

XML :

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="148dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/RadioGroup_MODE">
    <!-- android:buttonTint="@color/BouttonsRadio"-->

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="137dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Mode_J"
        android:id="@+id/BouttonRADIO_JOUR"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="137dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Mode_N"
        android:id="@+id/BouttonRADIO_NUIT"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RadioGroup>
```

JAVA :

```
final RadioButton radiobutton_mode_j = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.BouttonRADIO_JOUR);
    final RadioButton radiobutton_mode_n = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.BouttonRADIO_NUIT);
```

I use this code for check if it's this radiobutton which is checked :

```
radiobutton_mode_j.isChecked()
radiobutton_mode_n.isChecked()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
     int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

     RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

     Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
                    radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

**Edit**

Here is the full code as per your request:

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="148dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/RadioGroup_MODE">
    <!-- android:buttonTint="@color/BouttonsRadio"-->

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="137dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Mode_J"
        android:id="@+id/BouttonRADIO_JOUR"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="137dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Mode_N"
        android:id="@+id/BouttonRADIO_NUIT"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RadioGroup>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit" />
```

Activity:

```
 private RadioGroup radioGroup;
  private RadioButton radioButton;
  private Button btnDisplay;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);   

    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup_MODE);
    btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);

    btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                // get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            // find the radiobutton by returned id
                radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

            Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
                radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I'm a beginner in Android dev, and I don't understand what is your variable "radioButton"

Comment: @McNavy Ok i am updating my answer.

Comment: @McNavy You don't need to initialize radioButtons like you did, just follow the above code and accept it if its is useful.

Comment: Thanks, but I have a radiogroup with two radio buttons. I don't know how to adapt your solution with my code. Can adapt for me please?

Comment: @McNavy Have you tried above code? Plz tell. If you find the answer helpful and resolved your issue, please accept the answer and upvote. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup_MODE);
if(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1){
            //one of the Radiobuttons is checked

        }else {
            //none of the Radiobuttons is checked
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have a radiogroup with two radio buttons. I don't know how to adapt your solution with my code. Can adapt for me please?